# SBS 2003 to SBS 2011 migration, how to check why the old server is restarting?

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, windows-sbs-2003

We've migrated SBS 2003 to SBS 2011.  So far everything has gone smoothly.

We're in the final phase of migrating the last amount of data over. Our 21 days is up on Thursday. The old server restarting on its own now.

Is there a way I can check to be sure that our old server isn't restarting due to the 21 day grace period?

Is there any way to extend the 21 days?
Or roll it back?
Or does this take a call to Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

We did this successfully by [using these instructions](http://byronwright.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/stop-sbs-from-shutting-down.html):

> I've found a slightly more elegant solution to this problem rather
>   than just aggressively killing the process until Windows gives up
>   trying to start it again, and I'd like to share it in the hope that
>   Google will re-index and pick it up for others to use. You may have
>   noticed this service cannot be disabled via the MMC snap-in.
>
> My search term on google was: how to stop the SBCore service. Anyway,
>   down to business…
>
> - Tools you'll need – Process Explorer from http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/ProcessesAndThreads/ProcessExplorer.mspx
>
> As you probably know, you have a service called SBCore or "SBS Core
>   Services", which executes the following process:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sbscrexe.exe. If you kill it, it just restarts –
>   and if you try and stop it you are told Access Denied.
>
> If you fire up Process Explorer, you can select the process and
>   Suspend it, now we can start to disable the thing. Run regedit and
>   expand the nodes until you reach the following hive
>   /key:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SBCore Right
>   click this, hit permissions and give the "Administrators" group on the
>   local machine full access ( don't forget to replace permissions on
>   child nodes ). F5 in regedit and you'll see all of the values and data
>   under this key.
>
> Select the "Start" DWORD and change it from 2 to 4 – this basically
>   sets the service to the "Disabled" state as far as the MMC services
>   snap-in (and windows for that matter) is concerned.
>
> Next, adjust the permissions on the file
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sbscrexe.exe so that EVERYONE account is denied
>   any sort of access to this file. Then go back to process explorer, and
>   kill the sbscrexe.exe process, if it doesn't restart –
>   congratulations!
>
> Load up the services MMC snap-in and you should find that "SBS Core
>   Services" is stopped and marked as Disabled.

Note that doing this may put you in violation of the EULA. We did it because the migration did not get a chance to finish before I went on holidays; this tied the company over until after I got back and could finish the job.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was asked awhile ago and we are beyond the period for your specific situation, but just in case others see this thread I thought I'd respond.

The grace period can be extended by an additional 7 days if you are ready to demote the SBS 2003 to a member server.  To do this, you need to have all of Exchange migrated and then uninstall Exchange from the SBS 2003 (be sure to follow the migration guide for this).

Sorry I didn't catch this for your migration, but hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, there is no way to extend that limit. That is just the terms of the license and enforced by the software:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2008/02/22/small-business-server-2003-migration-update-943494-released.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943494

Comment: It actually was due to the grace period. The SBCore service was doing the 60-minute restart. It was doing this a full week early. We did find a work around so that we could finish our migration and take the server down: http://byronwright.blogspot.com/2009/07/stop-sbs-from-shutting-down.html

Comment: @Steve Of course, it does make sense if you remove that. Thank you for the update.